# How to make sure that viewWillLayoutSubviews / All View Calls have been made?

Tags: ios, uibutton, viewwillappear

I have the following case wherein I want to set a button as hidden after it has been set up in Autolayout.

So basically, say this method called was `- (void) hideSomeButton`. I call this method as :

```
BlahViewController *bVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:"Blah"] instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bVC animated:YES];
[bVC hideSomeButton];
```

I'm assuming that this is what the method calls should be :

```
1. init Method
2. viewDidLoad
3. viewWillAppear
4. viewWillLayoutSubviews (This has an explicit call making someButton.hidden = NO)
5. viewDidLayoutSubviews
6. hideSomeButton (This has an explicit call making someButton.hidden = NO)
```

However, `viewWillLayoutSubviews' is called twice. Thus, what happens is :

```
1. viewWillLayoutSubviews - Button Shown
2. hideSomeButton - Button Hidden
3. viewWillLayoutSubviews - Button Shown
```

BOOM! NO HIDDEN Button! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not call hideSomeButton from viewWillLayoutSubviews inside BlahViewController after calling [super viewWillLayoutSubviews] instead of calling it on bVC?